# MediaWiki-like Special Pages under SharePoint 2010 Wiki?

Tags: 2010, wiki, out-of-the-box, comparison

I watched [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DWkApP2wen8)  and wondered what those "latest pages", "popular pages", and "request pages" links in the left-hand menu? Are these standard SharePoint 2010 Server Wiki Features like the "Special Pages" with MediaWiki? Is there such a thing as automatically-generated special pages in Sharepoint 2010? I'm looking into migrating a MediaWiki site to SharePoint and I would love to see the special pages feature carry forward.

Francois

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [the series](http://office2010.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/take-sharepoint-server-2010-training-at-your-desk-HA101859255.aspx) of videos that includes the video you mention showcases the standard SharePoint 2010 and Office 2010 functionality. The links you ask about are built in.

Comment: Thanks, but you are basically just linking back to the same video I was talking about!

Comment: This site is supposed to help both the Original Poster and the other people who may have similar questions. I thought the link to the whole series that includes the video you linked to could be useful for them.  I edited the answer to make it clear.